# Mathematical Induction - Fractional Inequality

Tags: induction

[image]

I don't mean to ask without show of any working, but I would like to have some hints, I've tried dividing both sides by (1+h), however, it lead me nowhere.

Any hints as to how I should approach this question?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: by [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli's_inequality):

$$
1+nh \le (1+h)^n \tag{1}
$$

Then, since $0 \le h \le 1\,$:

$$
(1+h)^n(1-h)^n = (1-h^2)^n \le 1 \tag{2}
$$

Now multiply $(1)$ and $(2)$ together.

Comment: Thanks, but we are not suppose to have knowledge such as bernoulli's inequality. Managed to solve it without.

Comment: @user51515 That's precisely why it's a good idea to add some context when you post a question, otherwise no one can guess. `Managed to solve it` You should consider posting that as a self-answer, which is perfectly OK around here.